# Server-created events using Node JS

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

We are using node js, redis, php & mysql in our stack on Ubuntu 12.04.
It's an internal application, and we're trying to get real-time notifications working correctly.

There's a lot of code, let me know exactly which pieces you would like to see - I'll post them.

**Here's where I'm at:**
Whenever a user logs, the node index file (app.js) is triggered & puts the user's id, session id, socket id & a couple other variables into an object & uses redis-server as a data store for active connections. Connections are removed from the data store when a client logs out or closes their browser. This is & has been functioning accordingly.

**Here's the problem:**
Cron calls:

```
/var/www/node node notifications.js
```

Notifications.js makes an sql query & then needs to send out any pending messages that are waiting. Notifications.js can reach out to redis & grab the stored client websocket connection info.
So at this point, I have the message to send, the user's id, the (php) session id and the WebSocket ID.

I can not send a message back out to client bc the socket.io ws connection object has no connections.

I have exported the object in app

```
/* Include Default & Mandatory Modules */
var http            =       require('http')
, server            =       http.createServer().listen(3000)
, socketio          =       require('socket.io')
, socketioWildcard  =       require( 'socket.io-wildcard' )
, io                =       socketioWildcard( socketio ).listen(server)
, redis             =       require('redis')
, rclient           =       redis.createClient()
, util              =       require('util');

/* Export to other modules */
exports.socketio    =       io.sockets;
```

In other node libraries, that are called/triggered by browser events - I can simply

```
require(./app.js);
```

and use as such:

```
app.socketio.sockets[ app.socket_id ].emit('log.user.out',{'err':true,'msg':'You have been logged ....'});
```

What do I need to change in my Notification.js module to be able to send an event to a browser, when I have the appropriate WebSocket ID BUT the browser did not create an event ?

Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Use Redis as message queue to send message (events) between programs.

1) Create redis client

```
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();
```

2) **notification.js** publish events to queue with data.

```
var msg = {};//your message, user id, session id, websocket id
client.publish("socket_message", JSON.stringify(msg, null, 4));
```

3) **app.js** subscribed to channel

```
client.subscribe("socket_message");
client.on("message", function(channel, msg) {
  var message = JSON.parse(msg);
  //send any socket.io message to client there
});
```

Comment: I have read about pub/sub systems - haven't gotten my feet wet with them yet. This looks like a great solution for my problem. I'm implementing today, will have feedback by tomorrow. Thanks Nikolay !